# Type Bounds In Java Array (sort or minimum) Function

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

In Java, the Arrays.sort generic function is declared as follows:

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Can an example be provided when the above definition would succeed, but the following would not:

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<T> c)
```

Comment: You have a variable of type `Comparator<Number>` and want to sort an `Integer[]`. The second declaration would not accept that.

Comment: liskov substitution principle tells you that if you have a type `R`, and a `Comparator<R>`, you should be able to compare `T extends R` with that comparator.

Comment: @Clashsoft: Why can't the second declaration accept that? `Integer[]` is a subtype of `Number[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparator<CharSequence> onLength = Comparator.comparingInt(CharSequence::length);
String[] test = {"hello", "you"};
Arrays.sort(test, onLength);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
```

The above would fail if the signature was simply `sort(T[] a, Comparator<T> c)` - in that case, only a `Comparator<String>` would suffice.

You could have trivially written:

```
Comparator<String> onLength = Comparator.comparingInt(String::length);
```

but what if you already have a comparator, or there is a class that provides it for you? You can't just 'cast' a `Comparator<CharSequence>` to `Comparator<String>`.

The idea is: A thing that can compare any 2 fruits can of course compare any 2 apples. The user of the thing needs to tell the compiler that it works like that, and you do this by saying `<? super T>`.

Comment: "The above would fail if the signature was simply sort(T[] a, Comparator<T> c)" Why does it have to fail? -- if `T` were `CharSequence`, then all the types would be compatible.

Comment: No, because a `String[]` is not the same as a `CharSequence[]`. Generics are invariant by default, because that's how typevars have to work. You could write bogus code if it didn't work that way (example: `List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(); List<Number> numbers = ints; numbers.add(someDouble);` - you just added a double to a list of ints. What should happen if I call `ints.get(0)` now? That's why generics are invariant, and that's why you can't "just say T should be CharSequence and all is well".

Comment: Arrays are covariant. `String[]` is a subtype of `CharSequence[]`.

Comment: Only in the JLS, not in actual use. `ArrayStoreException` would occur. The concept of 'a mutable list of foos' _is inherently invariant_.

Comment: `sort()`, which just moves existing elements around, would never cause an `ArrayStoreException`. Your claim that "the above would fail" is not true.